# "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad." When ad is visible

Tags: admob, google-play-services

I am getting this error "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad." However my ad is visible.  There is more than enough room to display the ad (all the green area is ad area).  Will I still get credit for displaying the ad?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get credit when someone clicks on your add, not when the ad is displayed.
So the message is irrelevant.